# Condition if column from table is empty is not working?

Tags: arcpy, cursor, null

I want to make a loop where if a column is empty in a row to do something else. The  problem is that it can't determine the empty row. I tried as null, na , '',' ' and with double quotes and nothing.

```
for i in t_list:
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(i, ["name","num"]) as cur:
        for row in cur:
            if row[1] is not "''":
               print(row)
```

Gives:

```
nog1, num = '1'
nog2, ''
```

And it returns even the the empty rows

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To check for not na/none use:

```
if row[1] is not None
```

To check for both None and empty string use:

```
if row[1] not in ('', None)
```

Or simply:

```
if row[1]
```

Which will be true if value is not empty or None:

```
a = ''
if a:
    print('Not empty')
a = None
if a:
    print('Not None')
a = 'hello'
if a:
    print(a)
```

Outputs:

```
hello
```